# log4j in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, log4j, jtextpane

I'm currently trying to make Log4J log into a `JTextPane`. I want to use a TextPane because I want basic highlighting (e.g. errors are red and infos are green).

I have two loggers set up, one (the root-logger) logs everything into a file and the other (`guiLogger`) logs only some errors and infos on the GUI in a `JTextPane`.

The problem I'm currently facing is, that I can't get appending to the TextPane to work. What I currently have looks something like this:

```
public class Log extends AppenderSkeleton{

    private final JTextPane log;
    private final StyledDocument doc;

    public Log(){
        super();
        log = new JTextPane();
        doc = log.getStyledDocument();
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
        try {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Hello World!", null);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JTextPane getView(){
        return log;
    }
}
```

The Log4J config-file looks like this:

```
# The root-logger should log everything.
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, file

# Append the logs to a file.
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# [...]

# The logger which logs on the GUI (just some user-information).
log4j.logger.guiLogger = INFO, gui

# Append the logs to the GUI
log4j.appender.gui = mypackage.Log
# Formatting of the output:
log4j.appender.gui.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.gui.layout.ConversionPattern = %m%n
```

The `append()`-method gets called, and the `insertString()`-method performs clean (it does not enter the `catch`-block), but I don't see any content in the TextPane on the GUI.

What I have tried to fix this:

- Execute the `insertString()`-method using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`
- Execute the `insertString()`-method from a `SwingWorker`
- Methods like `validate()`, `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the `JTextPane`
- Not using the global `StyledDocument`-object but directly getting it from the `log`-instance: `log.getStyledDocument().insertString(0, "Hello World!", info_log);`
- The `setText()`-method of the `JTextPane` (only works in the constructor).

Since the `JTextPane` has no `fireContentChanged()`-method (or similar), I'm kind of lost here.

---

I have played around a bit more and found some other things:

- The `StyledDocument` gets updated (calling `getText()` shows that the text has been inserted).
- When I call the `append()` or `insertString()`-method directly from the compiler (after initializing the `StyledDocument` and the `JTextPane`), it all works fine.

Also, I checked which thread called the method by adding this to the `append()`-method body:

```
System.out.println("Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

It shows the following if I simply do two log-statements from somewhere in the code:

```
Thread: AWT-EventQueue-0
Thread: AWT-EventQueue-0
```

and when I call the `append()`-method directly from the constructor of the `Log`-class (plus the two logging-statements from above), it shows the following:

```
Thread: AWT-EventQueue-0
Thread: AWT-EventQueue-0
Thread: AWT-EventQueue-0
```

The first call appends the text probably. But the other two don't seam to work.

My GUI is build from the `AWT-EventQueue` by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. The two logging-calls are made in the same context (and therefore come from the EventQueue, too).

Comment: are you sure you're not duplicating the `org.apache.log4j.lf5.LF5Appender`?

Comment: @ʘleg this one looks a little "overloaded" for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text pane is private to the appender, and you don't have any getter for it. So I would guess that the GUI has a text pane, and the logger has another text pane it appends to.

That, or you're getting the text pane from a Log instance that is not the same as the Log instance that Log4j instantiates.

Also, the appender might be use by several threads, but the Swing components may only be accessed from the event dispatch thread. Every append to the text pane should be done inside a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call.

Comment: The `Log`-class has a `getView()`-method which returns the private `JTextPane`. I added it to the code-snipped. Since I'm not appending to the TextPane itself but to it's `StyledDocument` I'm not modifying it, or am I wrong here?

Comment: I added some more information to my question, please have a look.

Comment: How exactly do you get the text pane from the appender? Show us the code used to do that. My guess is that you Log4J and your code don't use the same Log instance.

Comment: By using the `getView()`-method which returns the `log`-instance. This is then added to the GUI. The method is in my questions code.

Comment: How do you get the Log instance (not the JTextPane instance)? i.e. How do you get the instance of your subclass of AppenderSkeleton on which you call getView(). I'm pretty sure that Log4J instantiates one, and you instantiates another one. Each has its own Log instance, hence its own JTextPane instance. I've tried your code, but made the JTextPane log field and getView methods static, and it works as expected.

Comment: HAH! I made both the `StyledDocument` and the `JTextPane` static, put them in a static-initializer and boom, everything works fine. I thought I missed something obvious, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether yu don;t call setText() or setContentType() and may be some more methods which recreate Document. Instead of saving reference to the document get it from pane.
Not

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Hello World!", null);
```

but

```
log.getStyledDocument().insertString(doc.getLength(), "Hello World!", null);
```

Comment: I don't call any of those mentioned methods. Getting the reference directly does not work, either. I added some more information to my question, please have a look.

Comment: +1 I send simlair (deleted) answer wrapped inside `Runnble#Thread`, but I got `What are you trying to show here?` by @Lukas Knuth, since Log4J's allows to save output to the Console, File or DB, he missed `API bridge` betweens `Log4J` and `Swing JComponents`